# Django using rest_framework url_pattern not mapping to model instance view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `Django python` application that uses `rest_framework` API. I want the API to map to `/api/v1/<object name>[/id]`. The `GET /api/v1/whs` gives a page that lists the Wh objects in the database (which is `MongoDB/Djongo/pymongo`).

**Problem:**
`GET /api/v1/whs/640444031170f24828f324bc/` does not call the `def get_object(self)` function (evidenced by the fact the print statement never runs). The Wh document with that `ObjectId` exists in the `MongoDB` database (verified). The request gives the following webpage output:

```
HTTP 404 Not Found
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

**Below is my code**

This is the portion of my **settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    ...
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

This is my **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from djongo.models import fields
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from djongo.models import fields

CHARFIELD_MAX_LENGTH = 1024

# Create your models here.
class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    _id = fields.ObjectIdField()
    external_id = models.CharField(max_length = CHARFIELD_MAX_LENGTH, null = True, blank = True,)
    options = models.JSONField(null = True, blank = True,)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null = False, blank = False,)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True,)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['created_at']

    def id(self):
        return self._id

class Wh(AbstractModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = CHARFIELD_MAX_LENGTH, null = False, blank = False,)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = CHARFIELD_MAX_LENGTH, null = False, blank = False,)
    map = models.JSONField( null = False, blank = False,)
    parent_wh = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'nested_whs', null = True, blank = True,)
    operator = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'whs', null = True, blank = True,)

    class Meta(AbstractModel.Meta):
        abstract = False
        verbose_name = 'wh'
        verbose_name_plural = 'whs'

    def __str__(self):
        return '[Wh' + self.name + ']'

class User(AbstractUser, AbstractModel):
    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        abstract = False
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

This is my **serializers.py**:

```
from .models import *
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ['password']

class WhSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    operator = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Wh
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is my **views.py**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from bson import ObjectId
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView
from .serializers import *

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

class WhViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Wh.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WhSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

class WhDetail(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Wh.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WhSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        id = self.kwargs.get('id')
        print(id)
        return get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), _id=ObjectId(id))
```

And last but not least, my **urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'whs', views.WhViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('wh/<str:id>', views.wh, name='wh'),
    path('api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('api/v1/whs/<str:id>', views.WhDetail.as_view(), name='whs'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelViewSet contains RetrieveModelMixin,so, why are you using unnecessary class WhDetail(RetrieveAPIView)? Anyway you can use RetrieveAPIView for it, but without get_object():

views.py

```
class WhDetail(RetrieveAPIView):
queryset = Wh.objects.all()
serializer_class = WhSerializer
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

urls.py

```
path(
    "api/v1/whs/<int:pk>/",
    WhDetail.as_view(),
    name="'whs",
)
```